# How can I list the names of the servers with "forEach()" function? | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i'm trying to get a list of the server names. I did already on server ids and it works perfectly fine but not to server names. This is how it starts with the server id which is working.

```
client.guilds.cache.keyArray().forEach(id => {
...
}
```

But now i'm trying for server names

```
client.guilds.name.cache.keyArray().forEach(name => {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `client.guilds.cache` is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), you can use [`mapValues`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=mapValues) :

```
client.guilds.cache.mapValues(guild => guild.name);
```

This will return the list of your guilds (or servers) names.

Comment: I have a question. When a server changes their name, how can I update that?  I'm using mongodb as a database, please tell me an example.

Comment: @randomname123 you can listen to a guild name change with the [`guildUpdate` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildUpdate) on the client.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time for that. I suggest you edit your question with the issues you are having (in details)

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it.